# Bookmarking in Trello

Tags: trello, bookmarks

How do you bookmark a page in Trello?  I need to share a link with a group of people so they can begin contributing to the board but the urls don't look clean.

Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 7):

Links to individual boards are not pretty - they look something like `https://trello.com/board/foobar/ddd7474fh29999dhf8cds` - but you can send this link to anyone and it will work. (Consider shortening it with bit.ly or similar, as a workaround.)