# How do I send a link to a shared Trello board?

Tags: trello, sharing, links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bookmarking in Trello](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19110/bookmarking-in-trello)

Is it possible to give or share a direct link to a particular Trello board? There's no direct link that I can see to either the list of boards, or to one board that I share with others.

Where might this simple functionality be hiding?

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the URL from the address bar in your browser and share that with others.

Try `Ctrl/Cmd + L` (or selecting with the mouse), then `ctrl/cmd + C` to copy.